# Getting IOException while opening a file from a share path

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

We are using `Desktop.open()` to open files. In some case this method is throwing an IOException:

```
Error message: The system cannot find the file specified.
java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:////userprofiles01/XDdata01/mm015633/Desktop/New%20folder/product/My%20Product/scripts/Logs/%5B2012-02-21%20131622-379%5D%20Interaction/log.html.
```

However the same code works fine when the file is located on the "C:\" drive. The issue only appears if:

1. File path is on a shared drive (not on "C:" drive) and
2. File path contains blank spaces or any special characters like "[" and "]".

**Examples:**

- Folder or file name contains blank spaces ie "(space)"
  `\\userprofiles01\XDdata01\mm015633\Desktop\Hi(space)Hello\log.html`
  `\\userprofiles01\XDdata01\mm015633\Desktop\HiHello\log(space)1.html`
- Folder name contains special characters "[" and "]"
  `\\filesrvwhq\india\Automation\MyProject\Mustak\[spacetest]\log.html`

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of reasearch, it appears to me that this is a known bug:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6780505
A possible workaround, I did not tried it, may be described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363056/1050015